# Android: how to set click events on ListView?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I'm looking to be able to open up a new view or activity when I click on an item in my ListView.

Currently I have a list of restaurants, and when i click on a particular restaurant I want it to open up another screen that will show its address, google map etc.

What I need help with is knowing how to set click events on the items in the list.
At the moment I dont have a database of the items, they're just Strings.
Can someone help me with getting me to this stage?

Thanks alot.

```
package com.example.androidrestaurant;
```

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.ListActivity;

public class Dundrum extends ListActivity {
    TextView selection;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DUNDRUM));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  }
```

static final String[] DUNDRUM = new String[] {

```
    "Ananda",
    "Brambles Cafe", "Brannigans", "Buona Sera",
    "Cafe Mao", "Cafe Mimo",
    "Dante", "Douglas & Kaldi Terrace Cafe",
    "Eddie Rockets",
    "Frango's World Cuisine",
    "Nando's",
    "Overends Restaurant @ Airfield House",
    "Pizza Hut",
    "Roly Saul",
    "Siam Thai","Smokey Joes","Sohag Tandoori",
    "TGI Friday","The Rockfield Lounge", "Winters Bar" };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do like this :

```
// Store your listview into local variable
ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

// Bind onclick event handler
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {

                      // Put in your code here, what you wanted trigger :)
              }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `ListView` in a `ListActivity`, override `onListItemClick()`. Otherwise, use `setOnItemClickListener()` with the `ListView`. In either case,  you are given a position that is the index into your array.

See [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Selection/List/) for an sample project.

Comment: I edited my code into the above post.
Do i need to add in a onListItemClick() in here to open up new activities?

Comment: You need to add an `onListItemClick()` to find out when list items get clicked.

Comment: Ok and i'm wondering about activities and views next.

If I have like 50 restaurants, surely I dont have to have 50 different activities/xml files in my project for each seperate one? 
What would be the best way of doing this?